# I can not import my published typescript library, with this error: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'tqt' in ..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I published a dead simple typescript module using this [tutorial](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/), and it is installed via

```sh
npm install --save tqt@1.0.0
```

When trying to use it in a program, I get this:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tqt' in '/home/akiva/Programming/frogcast/src'
```

from this:

```
import React from "react";
import { CA_PoliticalParty } from "tqt";

console.log(CA_PoliticalParty); // Anything that invokes this will error.
class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor() {
        super("");
    }
    render() { return ( <div> </div> )};
};

export default App;
```

With the relevant code that was published being this:

## TQt.ts

```js
// Canadian Enumerators
export enum CA_PoliticalParty {
    // Canadian Major National Political Parties
    None= "None",
    CPC = "CPC",
    GPC = "GPC",
    LPC = "LPC",
    NDP = "NDP",
    PPC = "PPC",
}
```

## index.ts

```js
export {CA_PoliticalParty} from './TQt'
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "tqt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Typescript Namespaces and Enums",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Akiva Avraham <akiva@linux.com>",
  "license": "GPL-2.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://akiva@git.launchpad.net/tqt"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "lib": ["es5","es6","dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing here? I played around with the settings only in very minor ways with no changes, and I followed the tutorial exactly as it is laid out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the TypeScript `outDir` does not match the package.json `main`. For your particular setup, it will work if you change `main` to `dist/index.js` (which is parallel to what you did correctly for `types`.)

[image]